# Why does every function make the reversed iterator empty?

Tags: python, function, iterator

I was writing code like this:

```
nums = [4, 1, 3, 2]
rev = reversed(nums)
rev2 = list(rev)
print(list(rev))
print(rev2)
```

the result:

```
[]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

So we can see that `rev` has no elements after the `list` function; it's not only Python's function does that; it also happened with the custom one:

```
def become_list(iter):
    result = []
    for i in iter:
        result.append(i)
    return result

nums = [4, 1, 3, 2]
rev = reversed(nums)
rev2 = become_list(rev)
print(list(rev))
print(rev2)
```

the result:

```
[]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
```

I wonder why this happened.

---

For the question, a code in my test showed that it was trying to call two sorted `rev` in one line:

```
nums = [4, 1, 3, 2]
rev = reversed(nums)
print(sorted(rev) == sorted(rev))
```

The answer is False. Because they are `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and `[]`. Though I have figured it out, why they are not equal, I still get confused and wonder why this happened.

Comment: iterators are by design one-time. Once you consume a value from an iterator, there's no going back.

Comment: extending @gog 's comment in your code `reversed` is returning iterator

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So in Python, there's a difference between an iterator and a list, tuple, dictionary, etc., but why will iterators need to be deleted after usage?

Comment: The iterator isn't deleted -- it is just consumed. It is hard to answer why questions since ultimately it is only the developers that can answer. It was a design decision. Iterators are supposed to be memory-efficient producers of items. Retaining initial state would have been less efficient. It is interesting to note that when Java 8 added iterators with their streams library, the semantics of their streams is the same consume then its gone as Python.